# React Native app that works offline is reloading when there's a change in the network or when the device's Wi-Fi is turned off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ethernet

I recently inherited a React Native project that is not "properly" organized (I need to refactor it and improve its structure). However, I took on this project to address a bug in the offline functionality: it reloads when switching from Wi-Fi to mobile data or when Wi-Fi is turned off, causing the user to lose their progress.

Additional information that might be helpful:

- The same issue occurs on both iOS and Android (which rules out it being a native problem).
- The issue persists in the development environment.

Could it be related to a library? Please help me with any insights you find useful.

Some libraries used in the project that I suspect might be related to the issue:

- react 16.8.6
- react native 0.60.9
- react-native-community/netinfo 4.4.0
- onesignal: ^3.9.0
- react-redux ^7.1.0
- redux ^4.0.4
- sockjs-client ^1.6.0
- webstomp-client ^1.2.6

I have been unable to pinpoint the issue despite thorough examination of the services, functions, etc.